# In Dojo, how to programmatically click root of a Tree?

Tags: dojo

I am creating a web application using Dojo, composed of a treeView in the left side and a Data Grid on its right. After being loaded,I want the root of the treeView to be focused and clicked, so that the content of the datagrid can be changed accordingly.

I haven't success in doing this..
Thanks for your help

Comment: There may be a logic problem on your page load... can you post your code here ?

Comment: Surely! Wait, I'll edit my code. And would you kind move your answer to the answer section? so that if it's okay, I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: @Philippe : sorry, I think I can't decomposed the right code to be pasted. Actually, I am building my application using this application as the start : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/tutorials/wa-dojotoolkit/index.html?ca=drs In this application, the data in the grid was shown up rightfully (without clicking the root node). But in my application, I must click the root node first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Philippe for the clue about logic problem. Because of this clue, I am able to focus my mind by searching the error code. I found it in the defintion of query of the grid. `<table id="jurnalGrid" dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" jsId="jurnalGrid" columnReordering="true" sortFields="['tanggal','kode_jurnal']" store="jurnalStore" query="{id: '*'}"` I think you can guess that my query string is not correct :) I still left the code from that link without changing it to suit my need. Thanks... –